# Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall the application

Tags: sql-server, ssms, installation

I am getting this error in Windows Server 2012 with Visual Studio 2012 installed trying to open SQL Server Management Studio 2012:

> Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall the application

I tried many things, including installing SQL Server Management Studio 2014, uninstalling, reinstalling… Then repairing VS2012, installing SSMS 2014 again. All to no avail.

Comment: Can you take a look at the error log to identify which component failed and post it on here?

Answer (score 8):

Uninstall the Visual Studio 2010 Shell, this was done by [downloading the installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1366).

Once downloaded, run the installer and remove the VS2010 Shell component. Once done, run the SQL 2014 Management Studio installer or do a repair on your existing installation, this will itself reinstall the VS2010 Shell components.

Then it opened for me.

In Order To Repair Sql Server Management Studio Do Below Steps -

1. Open Control Panel Then Click on Program and Features
2. Then Find Microsoft Sql Server 2012 , Right click on it and choose uninstall
3. Then uninstall wizard will open and Follow the wizard steps to uninstall it.

Comment: The link is dead now unfortunately. This one seems to work instead: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=1366

Comment: Link to download 
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/isolated-shell/

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this error started happening after a large number of Windows security updates were installed, and only occurred when I tried to open SSMS by using a runas command with the /noprofile switch. This had been working fine previously, but after the patching, the presence of the /noprofile switch caused this error to come up when opening SSMS 2014.

I also wasn't able to open Visual Studio 2010 using a runas /noprofile command either, which also had been working previously.

To resolve the issue, I did the following:

In a regular command prompt:

```
    Runas /user:xxx\yyyyy cmd
```

(where xxx\yyyy is the account that I am trying to run SSMS and VS as.)

In the new command prompt:

```
    C:
    cd\
    cd program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
    devenv /resetuserdata
```

After this, all my settings for Visual Studio were gone, but otherwise I was able to open both Visual Studio 2010 and SSMS 2014.